# decode special characters from SQL

Tags: php, json, html-entities

ok, so this is my DB, i have some titles in HTML entities and others with normal characters:

```
TITLE

MAM&Aacute;
MAMÁ
```

So my problem is when i call the titles:

```
/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($conn)
{
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test where title_test like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%' and test_stock<>0");

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $row_array['id'] = $row['id_test'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['title_test'];


        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This were the results:

```
OUTPUT

MAM&Aacute;
NULL
```

So i added `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);`:

and this where my results:

```
OUTPUT

MAM&Aacute;
MAMÁ
```

How can i DECODE the titles with HTML entities and make them print this:

```
OUTPUT

MAMÁ
MAMÁ
```

Answer (score 0):

The htmlspecialchars_decode function is what you are looking for.

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('&Aacute;')
```

Would produce:

```
Á
```

Comment: i tried htmlspecialchars_decode($row['title_test']); but still no luck i keep getting: MAM&Aacute; ... i think it has something to do with json_encode() at the end.

Comment: What do you see when you print out `$return_arr`?

Comment: this result: MAM&Aacute;

Comment: Are you sure you are applying htmlspecialchars_decode BEFORE adding to `$return_arr`? What does this output `print_r(array_map('htmlspecialchars_decode', $return_arr))`?

Comment: im using this script: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/ but problems comes when i want to call a title